# Postgres Temporal / Partitioning Implementation Strategy

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning, ddl, temporal

I am looking to add `VALIDTIME` temporal support to my application and would like to get some feedback.  It looks like Postgres doesn't have native temporal support yet (I know there are extensions), so I'd have to go with the manual strategy for now.  Logically, this is what I'm after:

```
CREATE TABLE MyPartitionedTable(
    c1 int, 
    ValidTS tstzrange -- VALIDTIME field
)
PARTITION BY LIST (
  (
    CASE WHEN CAST(UPPER(ValidTS) AS DATE) = DATE '9999-12-31' THEN 1 -- Store all current rows in one partition
    ELSE 0 -- Store everything else in another partition
    END
  )
)
```

**Temporal**

*Current row*: `UPPER(ValidTS) = '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'`
*Old row*: `UPPER(ValidTS) <> '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'`

*Temporal DELETE*: `UPDATE` the "Current row" and `set UPPER(ValidTS) = current_timestamp`
*Temporal INSERT*: `INSERT` "Current row"
*Temporal UPDATE*: temporal `DELETE` + temporal `INSERT` (must be done in same transaction)

*Temporal SELECT (CURRENT)*: `SELECT "Current row"`
*Temporal SELECT (AS OF)*: `SELECT ... WHERE ValidTS @> <AS_OF_TS>`

**Partitioning**

Postgres 10 supports native table partitioning, so I'd like to take advantage of that:

- partition for current rows (super-quick look up)
- partition for history rows (with sub-partitions if needed)

I've been playing around with it and there seems to be some limitations.  For example, I can't use a `CASE` statement like in the example above -- an error about `IMMUTABLE` expressions.  I think it has to do with using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.  Also, the documentation says you can't define `UNIQUE` / `PRIMARY KEY` constraints on the partitioned table.

**My questions**

1. How does my temporal setup look?  What is your setup?  Any tips or things to look out for?
2. What is your partitioning strategy with temporal data?  How do you ensure quick access to current rows?  Any things to watch out for?

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on your setup:

1. <strike>PostgreSQL cannot automatically move rows between partitions (yet).</strike>
   Support to automatically move rows between partitions has been added in PostgreSQL 11
2. I'd expect a `validfrom` and `validto` timestamp, but I can only see one timestamp in your description. How do you want to implement `AS OF`?
3. I don't think it is a good idea to store timestamps as text. Store it as `date` or `timestamptz`, then you don't have any problems with non-`IMMUTABLE` functions. Then I would use `infinity` and not an arbitrary date like `9999-12-31` for active rows.

I would not partition the table, but rather use indexes. If necessary, you can create partial indexes with `... WHERE validto = 'infinity'`. If all queries for current data include the same condition, these indexes will be used. I guess it depends on your queries what would be the best approach. Of course, to speed up sequential scans, only partitioning would help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  A few questions: 1) If PG doesn't automatically move rows between partitions, does that mean I need to manually create triggers to INSERT rows into an audit table?  How can PG call this native partitioning?  2) The ValidTS is a `tstzrange` data type, so it stores the `validFrom` and `validTo` in the same field, like a `PERIOD` data type

Comment: The timestamps will be stored in `tstzrange` field, no strings.  I didn't know about the `infinity` value, though, that's what I need to use.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: And that's a good tip about using a sparse index with `WHERE validTo = 'infinity'`.  Thanks!  I haven't done performance tuning on Postgres before, so this is all new to me.  How fast would that lookup be to get only the current row data?  Would that be similar in performance to doing the same lookup with a non-temporal table?

Comment: Also (last comment), I read that the PG 10's table partitioning implementation will still create separate sub-tables and not store all the table data in a single table.  Is that true?  That seems like a lot of maintenance.  In Teradata, the native temporal support is so easy.  You just specify a VALIDTIME field, and do everything else like normal.  It automatically takes care of all DML, all the data's in the same table.  It seems like PG is not quite there yet.

Comment: **About partitioning:** It is a new feature, so there are still things missing. Moving data between partitions on `UPDATE` will probably be in v11. Partitions are implemented as tables, but as long as that's "under the hood", it shouldn't bother you. **About timestamps:** Ok, a `tstzrange` makes sense. **About indexes:** A lookup via index is as fast on a partitioned table as on a non-partitioned one. Only sequential scans are affected, but if the number of current values is small enough, an index scan on the whole partial index would still beat a sequential scan on the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I appreciate it.